# Is there any place on Grooveshark systematically to flag songs that are "bad"?

Tags: grooveshark

I find a lot of songs refuse to play at all, or cut out halfway through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to flag the song by doing the following:

- Hover your mouse over the song until you see the options menu come up.
- The options menu is represented by a "+" with a down arrow next to it.
- Click the gear, choose the "Flag Song" option and select what is wrong with the song from the menu.

  [image: Flag a song in Grooveshark]

You should flag a song if it will not play, skips, is low-quality, mislabeled, contains explicit lyrics, or has the wrong album art.

[Taken from this Grooveshark Help article](http://help.grooveshark.com/customer/portal/articles/2112-Song-info-is-incorrect)

Comment: Oh, awesome. I somehow share songs all the time without ever noticing that link.

Comment: Hmm, actually, I just checked and it doesn't seem to be there anymore. I guess they took it out.

Comment: @chuzzum: Are you sure? I've just logged on and the option appears for me.

Comment: Ah, I see. You have to select the options menu when the song is in the "now playing" area, if you select it from a song in the library area it only shows the add to playlist and sharing options. That may explain why I never noticed it. :)

Comment: Is there some way to flag a song that is not in the playlist?